# Rendering issue in large Sencha toch list

Tags: sencha-touch

I am using Sencha Touch list component which contains around 1000 records.

Scrolling of list is made false.

When I am using it on chrome browser, it works fine.
But when I run it on iPad safari, it gives **Javascript execution exceeded timeout** Error.
Also,when i select a list item, selection is not rendered properly.

Please, Help me.Its urgent.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing anything complex in your list-item template? Make sure your template is very simple, as of course it is going to be rendered repeatedly in a loop. Especially stay away from running any sub-template/sub-loops within each item.

For larger lists you might also want to take a look at [MahlerFreak's](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?121225-High-Performance-Large-List-component-UxBufferedList) [BufferedList](https://github.com/Lioarlan/UxBufList-Sench-Touch-Extension) component. I'm currently using it in a project with nearlly 10K items with much success.

I've needed to tweak it a little for my use-case, but it's nicely written and easy to work with.

Comment: But I want to render all my list items simultaneously since scroll is false for the list